# How do I sketch this graph, when I can only find the y-intercept and vertex?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I want to sketch the graph of this function:

> $y = x^2 + 2$

Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is $1$, the graph opens upwards.

When $y = 0$, I find that the graph does not cut the $x$-axis. (It is above it.)

When $x = 0$, I find that the graph cuts the $y$-axis at $(0, 2)$.

Hence, the equation of the line of symmetry is $x = 0$.

I still do not know the steepness of the parabola.

From this limited information, how do I sketch the graph of this function without using graphing software?

What additional formula(s) or method(s) would I need to sketch this graph? A demonstration based on my problem would be helpful.

Comment: You may find as many points of the graph as you like.... (0,1),(1,2), .....what is the problem?

Comment: If I only find points and join them up, I will not get the smooth curve of a parabola. Also I am trying to sketch the curve, not draw it.

Comment: You mean to sketch it with compass and ruler or other devices?

Comment: Don't join the points by segments, join them by smooth curves, there is somehow no exact way to draw it perfectly without using software, but you can get very close to the exact graph by plotting some more and more close points.

Comment: @dmtri No, to sketch it by hand just using algebra, axes and a pen.

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj thank you for your help

Comment: Observe that the graph is that of $y=x^2$ shifted upwards by two units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct thus far. You could include several more points in your graph, such as $x=1,2,4,\ldots$. This would already give you a good idea of the ''steepness'' of the function.

Then you could study the derivative of your function, to find its slopes at various points:
$$
(x^2+2)' = 2x,
$$
so you already know that at $x=\frac12$ you have a slope of $1$ and at $x=-\frac12$ a slope of $-1$. Then find the two $x$'s where the slope is twice that, and so forth.

This should already be more than enough to sketch a graph of the function.

Comment: is your example my problem or another one? Please could you clarify on the slope in your example, it’s a bit confusing.

Comment: Of course it's your example. Isn't $y=x²+2$ your function?

Comment: Yes. Please clarify on the slope, the text is a bit confusing.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between derivative and slope?

Comment: not before I asked this question. I had to google it.

Comment: So now you understand it?

Comment: yes. Thanks for helping